# Make textfield hidden but still editable?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, applescript

I am trying to make an application where you drop a file, and the path is written down to a variable. To do this, I have made a textField, and fixed the other stuff. So it works, but instead of just seeing the path in plain text, I want the user to see nothing.

I though this would work by making my Text Field "hidden", but that also means it's not editable. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how you drop a file on a text field and fixed the other stuff means?

Comment: @bolnad I mark it, then drop a file on it. It shows me the path, it's built in. With "the other stuff" I just meant making the contents into a variable first putting `property textField : missing value` under IBOutlets, and then         `set iconpath to textField's stringValue() as text`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this

```
NSTextField *textField =[[NSTextField alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(16, 16, 250, 20)];
[textField setBordered:NO];
[textField setDrawsBackground:YES];
[textField setTextColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[textField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
```